# Join through bridging table with one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `Products` table, which maps to a bridging table that contains all of the items said product comprises of, so Product A could be comprised of several items or just one. (OTM)

The `product_sub_item_bridge` looks like this,

```
+------------+----------------------------+
| product_id | client_sub_product_item_id |
+------------+----------------------------+
|        137 |                        332 |
|        138 |                        333 |
|        139 |                        334 |
|        140 |                        332 |
|        140 |                        335 |
+------------+----------------------------+
```

So say a client orders product **140**, items **332** and **335** will be inserted into a table called `client_sub_products` which houses the relationship to the order and the items themselves that are stored in the `client_sub_product_items` table.

What I would like to do now is get all of the `client_sub_products`, group them by the `client_order_id` and maybe `GROUP_CONCAT()` the id's, and somehow join the `Products` table onto it via the bridging table, so that I can get a list containing the `COUNT()`, for all of the`Products` that are comprised of those exact `client_sub_product_items`. Like so...

```
+--------------+---------------------+
| product_name | count(product_name) |
+--------------+---------------------+
|    Product A |                  15 |
|    Product B |                  25 |
+--------------+---------------------+
```

Here is what I have thus far,

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`client_sub_products`.`client_sub_product_item_id`) FROM `client_sub_products` LEFT JOIN `client_sub_product_items` ON `client_sub_product_items`.`id` = `client_sub_products`.`client_sub_product_item_id` GROUP BY `client_sub_products`.`client_order_id` ORDER BY `client_sub_products`.`client_order_id` ASC;
```

I can't seem to get past the bridging table, I am not sure how I can join the `client_sub_product_items` onto the `Products` through the bridging table, because there are products that have more than one `client_sub_product_item` related to it, I seem to be confusing myself there.

I hope I have explained myself adequately, and not just confused everyone... please let me know if I should try clarify anything mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Why associate the subproducts to the client if the subproducts are not orderable entities?  Why not just assign the products to the client, as it would be easy to derive the subprodcuts for each client from that?  As it stands right now you have no definitive way to determine whether subproduct 332 from your example is related to product 137 or 140.

Comment: It seems to me that you would just then need to version the product. And relate the client to the version of the product that is in effect at the time. If you are being asked to implement new functionality and it requires DB schema changes, then so be it. I have no idea how you are going to map sub products to products without it, ESPECIALLY given the added context that the subproducts related to a product may change over time.